# Return value from void method/function

Tags: java, arrays

I need to implement a java function/method that converts csv to array on my interface, however as the function's type is void, it doesn't return anything on the interface (it works on my local console though and prints the array).

This is my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestImpl implements Test
{


    public void tricsv(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "filetoconvert.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] cell = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println("Result= " + cell[0]+ "");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How about using a callback as a method to deliver the result back?

Comment: thanks for answering, how could I do that please? i'm very beginning with Java.

Comment: Just save the csv's content in a variable and add a "get" method, that returns that variable. After calling the tricsv function, just call the getter..

Comment: thanks any idea how I could do that please?

Comment: any reason why the method is void??? if you need an array out of the method then shouldn't the return type be an array.

Comment: The return type for method `tricsv()` **must** be `void`, correct? And the method **must** take a single parameter whose type is `String[]`? Why do you have these limitations? Why can't you just write a method that is passed the name of a CSV file and returns a `String` array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    public class TestImpl implements Test
    {
    private String[] cell;

     public String getValue(int index) {
return cell[index];
}
        public void tricsv(String[] args) {

            String csvFile = "filetoconvert.csv";
            String line = "";
            String cvsSplitBy = ",";

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    cell = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                    System.out.println("Result= " + cell[0]+ "");

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: thanks for answering me, but if I call the function "getValue(int index)", it will not obviously run the tricsv method because it's after getValue(int index) function and not included in it?

Comment: I thought it would be self explanatory. So you need to first call tricsv function and then make second method call to getValue